# Spark streaming printing top-k results of a dstream

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am dabbing with hadoop platforms and on of the things that I am experimenting with is Spark-Streaming API. I am trying to read a file stream to count number of words after every x-seconds (accumulated sum of the history). Now I want to print the top-k words onto a file. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
# sort the dstream for current batch
sorted_counts = counts.transform(lambda rdd: rdd.sortBy(lambda x: x[1], ascending=False))

# get the top K values of each rdd from the transformed dstream
topK = sorted_counts.transform(lambda rdd: rdd.take(k))
```

I am able to print the output to console/log file using:

```
sorted_counts.pprint(k)
```

But the problem is when I try to print it to a file using:

```
topK.saveAsTextFiles(out_path)
```

or even if I try to print topK to the console as:

```
topK.pprint()
```

I get the following error,

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_jrdd'

which I assume is because rdd.take(k) return actual list instead of an rdd. How can I work around it? Also I want to generate different file for each newly computed word count... i.e. a new output file every x-seconds (which is guaranteed with saveAsTextFiles(). I am using python to program this, if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: `sorted_counts.transform(lambda rdd: sc.parallelize(rdd.take(k)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no API that would allow you to do that. But you can workaround:

```
rdd.zipWithIndex().filter(<filter with big index>).map(<remove index here>)
```

Another solution would be (w/o sorting):

```
sc.parallelize(rdd.top(...))
```

This way you don't need to sort all the RDD, but only to take biggest elements and then create RDD from them.

Comment: I've edited my answer - added, as i think, a better solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked. The first one that is. Will try the second one and see what happens.